# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Tags: node.js, typeerror, config, dotenv

This is my `app.ts` file:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import config from "config";
import responseTime from "response-time";
import connect from "./utils/connect";
import logger from "./utils/logger";
import routes from "./routes";
import deserializeUser from "./middleware/deserializeUser";
import { restResponseTimeHistogram, startMetricsServer } from "./utils/metrics";
import swaggerDocs from "./utils/swagger";

const port = config.get<number>("port");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(deserializeUser);

app.use(
  responseTime((req: Request, res: Response, time: number) => {
    if (req?.route?.path) {
      restResponseTimeHistogram.observe(
        {
          method: req.method,
          route: req.route.path,
          status_code: res.statusCode,
        },
        time * 1000
      );
    }
  })
);

app.listen(port, async () => {
  logger.info(`App is running at http://localhost:${port}`);

  await connect();

  routes(app);

  startMetricsServer();

  swaggerDocs(app, port);
});
```

And I do get this error message:

```
yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.17
warning package.json: License should be a valid SPDX license expression
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/app.ts
[INFO] 14:02:52 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.6.3)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\A\Desktop\desktop\base_code\back_bc_node\src\app.ts:3:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\A\Desktop\desktop\base_code\back_bc_node\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-16796532812275466.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-16796532812275466.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (C:\Users\A\Desktop\desktop\base_code\back_bc_node\node_modules\ts-node-dev\lib\hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
[ERROR] 14:02:52 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
```

Why do I get this error message? I had this code already working with my previous app with `dotenv  version 10` but when I copied it in my new app with `dotenv    version 16` I get this error message.

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "back_bc_node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Commercial",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.10",
    "nanoid": "^3.3.2",
    "pino": "^7.10.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^7.6.1",
    "prom-client": "^14.0.1",
    "response-time": "^2.3.2",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
    "zod": "^3.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/config": "^0.0.41",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.181",
    "@types/nanoid": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "@types/pino": "^7.0.5",
    "@types/response-time": "^2.3.5",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, here, but can't you just `const conf = dotenv.config()` then read from that `conf` variable? `dotev.config` also makes all the configuration accessible through the `process.env` property object. What is `import config ...` trying to do? That's isn't being imported properly if it is a static JSON file; or if it isn't type-supported may need to be `import * as config from 'config';` or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

Try to replace:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
```

for this:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem too and I solved it by:

Create a new project, move the important files in the old project (for me, all the src files in the Vue project), then start the project, success!

Comment: This is more or less what I did... but I did it by deleting the package-lock files and node_modules then did a new npm install.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I had to add `"esModuleInterop": true,` to tsconfig.json, e.g.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["@testing-library/cypress", "cypress", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["../cypress.config.ts", "**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

this is because you are trying to use the syntax for commonJS in es modules. The dotenv.config function is for commonJS and uses TypeScript ES modules. For better usage have a look at dotenv's doc here:

[dotenv documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import)

Comment: Is that really the root cause though? Isn't module import syntax defined by the transpiler configuration? Here, the code is complaining about the `config` package, _not_ the `dotenv` package.